# Can I flash a Motorola Charm with a T-mobile update?

Tags: motoblur, motorola-charm

I recently bought a Motorola Charm with a Motoblur logo on it, but it doesn't appear to actually have Motoblur installed! There's no message widget, no Facebook update widget, no sign in for first use - nothing. Just a normal Android system. I am wondering what phone I actually have, and if I can update my phone with T-mobile's "Blur_Version.0.2.6005.MB502.T-Mobile.en.US" image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but in my experience it does not work well and you can't downgrade afterward. I'd recommend that you do NOT flash that T-Mobile updated ROM.